# How to query data from a table where **created_at** date = **today's date** ?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I want to query data from my **inventories** table where **created_at date** = **today date**

How do I do that in Laravel ? I tried

```
date_default_timezone_set ('America/New_York');
$today = date("d"); // 18 ( since today is 2/18/2015 )
```

`$inventories = Inventory::where( 'created_at' ,'=', $today )->get();`

I got 0 result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just compare the day of the month with a timestamp. Try this instead:

```
$today = Carbon::now()->toDateString();
$inventories = Inventory::whereRaw('DATE(created_at) = ?', [$today])->get();
```

---

Background info: `Carbon` is a DateTime library that Laravel uses. It makes things a bit easier but of course you could get the current date with `date()` as well. However `date("d")` will not return the current date but actually just the day of the month. The full date would be `date('Y-m-d')`.

Comment: Do you know how to convert the my **created_at** date into day_of_week ? For Example, since today = 2/18/15 Wednesday will return 3. I tried to use `jddayofweek() `, but no luck so far.